# How to install the XDS package on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

Can some one guide me on installing the `XDS` package on Ubuntu. Here is the **package** *[link](http://xds.mpimf-heidelberg.mpg.de/)*

Answer (score 3):

It is a stand alone executable file, just run these commands

```
wget ftp://ftp.mpimf-heidelberg.mpg.de/pub/kabsch/XDS-INTEL64_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
```

Now extract it

```
tar xvzf XDS-INTEL64_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
```

This will create a folder called `XDS-INTEL64_Linux_x86_64` in your `/home`, in here you will find all the executables, just call them in a terminal, for example

```
cd XDS-INTEL64_Linux_x86_64
./xds
```

To install the `xds veiwer` GUI use these steps

```
wget downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xds-viewer/xds-viewer/xds-viewer-0.6/xds-viewer-0.6?r=http%3A%2F%2Fxds-viewer.sourceforge.net%2F&ts=1459522373&use_mirror=iweb
chmod +x xds-viewer-0.6?r=http%3A%2F%2Fxds-viewer.sourceforge.net%2F
./xds-viewer-0.6?r=http%3A%2F%2Fxds-viewer.sourceforge.net%2F
```

You can find the file `xds-viewer-0.6?r=http%3A%2F%2Fxds-viewer.sourceforge.net%2F` in your `/home` directory, feel free to rename it what ever you like.

[image]

Tested on 15.10

Comment: I try to install with `./xds` but it gives following error ` ***** XDS ***** (VERSION Oct 15, 2015  BUILT=20151231)   1-Apr-2016
 Author: Wolfgang Kabsch
 Copy licensed until 30-Sep-2016 to
  academic users for non-commercial applications   
 No redistribution.

  !!! ERROR !!! CANNOT OPEN OR READ XDS.INP`

Comment: You don't install it, it is an executable, you must give it an argument `./xds someargumenthere` or what ever executable fits your needs. As you don't give much information, I can't be more specific as I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, I understand now. I have notes to deal with this.

Comment: You can put the xds executables in `/usr/local/bin/` to call them like applications if you prefer.

Comment: you mean move the whole `XDS-INTEL64_Linux_x86_64` directory in `/usr/local/bin/` and call the application from the `/home` directory by `./xds`.

Comment: and how can I create an alias pointing to my application. As on this page   https://www.helmholtz-berlin.de/forschung/oe/em/soft-matter/forschung/bessy-mx/xdsapp/installation-instructions_en.html.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, so in addition to Mark's answer above, you need to set up the search paths too, for the programs to work properly. As you are probably using bash in Ubuntu, open `.bashrc` in your home folder and add these lines. With the path set up, you also won't need to set up aliases. Full instructions are at [Downloading and Installation of XDS](http://xds.mpimf-heidelberg.mpg.de/html_doc/downloading.html):

```
export PATH=full_path_name_to/XDS-INTEL64_Linux_x86_64:$PATH
export KMP_STACKSIZE=8m
```